# How to Implement Single Log out for All application using ADFS Federation

Tags: single-sign-on, adfs, federation

I am going to implement SSO using an on-premises ADFS 4.0 with a federation service. I have done code for the login and its working fine but I want to develop Single log out functionality.

When I do log out from one website then the user must be automatically logged out from all the applications which are configured in ADFS server.

Following is my code:

**StartUp.Auth FIle**

```
            string adfs = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdfsMetadataEndPoint"];
            string realm = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Wtrealm"];
            string reply = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Wreply"];

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
                CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager()
            });

            app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
            {
                MetadataAddress = adfs,
                Wtrealm = realm,
                Wreply = reply,
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive
            });

            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
```

**logout Action:**

```
public void LogOff()
        {
            var owinContext = this.Request.GetOwinContext();
            var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties();
            authProperties.RedirectUri = new Uri(this.HttpContext.Request.Url, new UrlHelper(this.ControllerContext.RequestContext).Action("Login")).AbsoluteUri;

            owinContext.Authentication.SignOut(authProperties);

            WSFederationAuthenticationModule.FederatedSignOut(
                new Uri("https://xxxxxxx/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0"),
                new Uri("https://localhost:44320/Home/Index"));

            //AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

Comment: What is the question? Also SLO is usually a SAML feature.

Comment: I am using federation not a SAML